# Unable to call objects from XML in application

Tags: android, xml, textview

In my application, I don't seem to be able to call any of the layout objects in my application. the application will crash if i access any class that includes code which is using the XML file. lines like this

```
mButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.get);
cweight   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.cweight);
nweight   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.nweight);
t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.out);
```

These lines of code have worked before and the layout files they are called exist.

the logcat for this is below and looking at it i cannot see where the problem came from. specially since this code works days before.

```
05-23 16:12:43.790: E/AndroidRuntime(313): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-23 16:12:43.790: E/AndroidRuntime(313): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.b00348312.workout/com.b00348312.workout.WorkoutChoice}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-23 16:12:43.790: E/AndroidRuntime(313):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
05-23 16:12:43.790: E/AndroidRuntime(313):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
05-23 16:12:43.790: E/AndroidRuntime(313):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
05-23 16:12:43.790: E/AndroidRuntime(313):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
05-23 16:12:43.790: E/AndroidRuntime(313):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-23 16:12:43.790: E/AndroidRuntime(313):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-23 16:12:43.790: E/AndroidRuntime(313):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
05-23 16:12:43.790: E/AndroidRuntime(313):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-23 16:12:43.790: E/AndroidRuntime(313):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-23 16:12:43.790: E/AndroidRuntime(313):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
05-23 16:12:43.790: E/AndroidRuntime(313):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
05-23 16:12:43.790: E/AndroidRuntime(313):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-23 16:12:43.790: E/AndroidRuntime(313): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-23 16:12:43.790: E/AndroidRuntime(313):  at com.b00348312.workout.WorkoutChoice.onCreate(WorkoutChoice.java:67)
05-23 16:12:43.790: E/AndroidRuntime(313):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
05-23 16:12:43.790: E/AndroidRuntime(313):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
05-23 16:12:43.790: E/AndroidRuntime(313):  ... 11 more
```

ok so looking through solutions given the consensus seems to be that its the null pointer exception on line 67 but that is the first line i have given above. another solutions given is to use the setContent(view view) which i have done at the beginning on my onCreate method.

the class works perfectly fine when the lines given above are absent and they have worked before so i am not sure where the problem is.

Comment: Did you clean up your project and build again? Sometimes Eclipse sucks.

Comment: What is line 67 of WorkoutChoice.java?

Comment: 05-23 16:12:43.790: E/AndroidRuntime(313): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-23 16:12:43.790: E/AndroidRuntime(313):  at com.b00348312.workout.WorkoutChoice.onCreate(WorkoutChoice.java:67)

Comment: As in @compuguru answer, you need to call setContentView() with the layout you are using before resolving any view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what your `Activity` is using, there's a couple things that could be wrong.  Have you done [`setContentView(View view)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setContentView%28android.view.View%29) if you're just setting the view?  Otherwise, if you're inflating the view, you need to call `view.findViewById(id)`.  That way it calls it on the view you just inflated, otherwise it won't find it.

EDIT: One quick note, I believe you need to call `setContentView(View view)` before you do the finding of views, so `setContentView(View view)` need to be before you called `findViewById(id)` if you are doing things that way.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the problem is at `WorkoutChoice`, line 67. You are using an object whose value is null:

```
05-23 16:12:43.790: E/AndroidRuntime(313): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-23 16:12:43.790: E/AndroidRuntime(313):  at com.b00348312.workout.WorkoutChoice.onCreate(WorkoutChoice.java:67)
```